# C++ compiler giving same memory location to two variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, structure

Following is the code where I have defined a structure with four variables. First two are arrays with 3 elements each. Other two variables are scalars. I tried using vc++, g++ and an online compiler to compile this code. However, for all three cases, the memory address of the last element of 'vel' array and the address of the variable 'kinetic' turns out to be same. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct molec
{
    double pos[3] = {0,0,0},vel[3] = {0,0,0},kinetic = 0,potential = 0;
};

int main()
{
    const int n = 5;
    molec particle[5];

    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Particle no: " << i+1 << endl;
        cout << "Coordinates: [ " << &(particle[i].pos[1]) << ", " << &(particle[i].pos[2]) << ", " << &(particle[i].pos[3]) << "]" << endl;
        cout << "Velocities: [ " << &(particle[i].vel[1]) << ", " << &(particle[i].vel[2]) << ", " << &(particle[i].vel[3]) << "]" << endl;
        cout << "Kinetic energy: " << &(particle[i].kinetic) << endl;
        cout << "Potential energy: " << &(particle[i].potential) << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I got when I compiled it using vc++

```
Particle no: 1
Coordinates: [ 000000A01012F918, 000000A01012F920, 000000A01012F928]
Velocities: [ 000000A01012F930, 000000A01012F938, 000000A01012F940]
Kinetic energy: 000000A01012F940
Potential energy: 000000A01012F948

Particle no: 2
Coordinates: [ 000000A01012F958, 000000A01012F960, 000000A01012F968]
Velocities: [ 000000A01012F970, 000000A01012F978, 000000A01012F980]
Kinetic energy: 000000A01012F980
Potential energy: 000000A01012F988

Particle no: 3
Coordinates: [ 000000A01012F998, 000000A01012F9A0, 000000A01012F9A8]
Velocities: [ 000000A01012F9B0, 000000A01012F9B8, 000000A01012F9C0]
Kinetic energy: 000000A01012F9C0
Potential energy: 000000A01012F9C8

Particle no: 4
Coordinates: [ 000000A01012F9D8, 000000A01012F9E0, 000000A01012F9E8]
Velocities: [ 000000A01012F9F0, 000000A01012F9F8, 000000A01012FA00]
Kinetic energy: 000000A01012FA00
Potential energy: 000000A01012FA08

Particle no: 5
Coordinates: [ 000000A01012FA18, 000000A01012FA20, 000000A01012FA28]
Velocities: [ 000000A01012FA30, 000000A01012FA38, 000000A01012FA40]
Kinetic energy: 000000A01012FA40
Potential energy: 000000A01012FA48
```

Can anyone confirm that this problem is for sure repeatable? If yes, what is the problem or why this would happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Array indices start at `0`.

Comment: The memory address of the last value of 'vel' array of each particle element is exactly same as respective 'kinetic' variable. Which means that both 'particle[i].vel[3]' and 'particle[i].kinetic' points to the same memory location which should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vel` array has only three entries. But you print out the address of the fourth entry. It's not surprising that that happens to be the same address as the next object in the structure. Change `vel` to have four entries or print out the address of the third entry and your problem will go away.

vel[0] <- first entry
vel[1] <- second entry
vel[2] <- third entry
vel[3] <- fourth entry